# JavaScript ／ オブジェクトを構成し直した上で、配列へ格納したい

Tags: javascript

元オブジェクト
KEY VALUE
{tokyo,4},
{osaka,9}

を、

変更後オブジェクト
KEY VALUE

{area,tokyo}
{num,4},

{area,osaka}
{num,9}

と構成し直した上で、さらに下記のように、「元オブジェクト要素数」だけ数がある配列に入れたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

配列
INDEX   VALUE
0 変更後オブジェクトの一つ目の組み合わせ
1 変更後オブジェクトの二つ目の組み合わせ

※変更後オブジェクトのキー名「area」「num」は固定名です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ tokyo: 4, osaka: 9 }
```

というオブジェクトを、

```
[
    { area: 'tokyo', num: 4 },
    { area: 'osaka', num: 9 }
]
```

というオブジェクトの配列に変換したい、ということで合っていますか？
やるならこんな感じだと思います。

```
var obj = { tokyo: 4, osaka: 9 };
var result = [];
for (var area in obj) {
    result.push({ area: area, num: obj[area] });
}
```

`Object.keys()`と`Array.prototype.map()`に対応している最近のブラウザなら、tutinocoさんの回答のようにも書けます。

```
var obj = { tokyo: 4, osaka: 9 };
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (area) {
    return { area: area, num: this[area] };
}, obj);
```

この程度ならどっちを選んでも好みの問題だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

こういうことでよろしいのでしょうか。

```
var obj = [{tokyo: 4}, {osaka: 9}];

var result = obj.map(function(v){
  var o={};
  for(w in v){ o.area=w; o.num=v[w]; }
  return o;
});

console.log(result); // -> [{area:"tokyo", num:4}, {area:"osaka", num:9}]
```

Comment: 元データが配列ではなくオブジェクトだった場合はどう書くのでしょうか？　var obj = {};obj.tokyo = 4;obj.osaka = 9;